# Iterate over some .csv and overwrite them

Tags: pandas, csv, for-loop

I have around 160 csv files I would like to overwrite using a for loop. Each .csv file has data that follows this structure:

```
9.87
8.77
8.67
9.88
7.65
7.38
8.45
```

I want to overwrite each .csv file and only keep the first and last number. In the end it should look something like this:

```
9.87





8.45
```

Please note that I would like to keep the spaces between the first and last number blank. Also, some of the .csv files have blanks for the first three elements. So the for loop should be flexible enough to delete the numbers between the first number that appears in the .csv and the last one. For example, this would be the result for one of the .csv files that has blanks before the first number appears:

```
  -
  -
 9.43



 4.11
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming that you are loading those CSV using `pd.read_csv`:

```
import pandas as pd

csv_path = ['my/path/to1.csv', 'my/path/to2.csv']

results = pd.DataFrame()
for p in csv_path:
    df = pd.read_csv(p)
    df.iloc[1:-1] = '-'
    results = results.append(df)
```

put all your path in 1 list, then iterate over it, select the first and last row and append it to a result dataframe.

Comment: Thanks! But it keeps throwing this error:

`AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-fbbb01944329> in <module>()
      2 for p in csv_path:
      3     df = pd.read_csv(p, header = None)
----> 4     df = df.iloc[1:-1] = ' '
      5     results = results.append(df)
      6     results.to_csv(f'{p}.csv', index = False, index_label = False, header = False)

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'iloc' `

Comment: I adjusted the answer